# Getting the coordinates of a point inside an overlapping rectangle

Tags: javascript, graphics, rectangles

I have two colored rectangles, both being represented by a 2D array that directly corresponds to their coordinates(ex. [0][0] is the same as (0,0)). Things such as the width, height, and origin of each rectangle are known.
As of now, I want their colors to "blend" in the area they intersect. Detecting if a point is within both rectangles is easy enough, and I have the point's coordinates relative to the origin of my first rectangle as it is the one I am iterating through for color blend checking.
My problem is *getting the point's coordinates relative to the ***second rectangle**** so I may get that rectangle's color at that point. Here is a visual example of what I mean.

[Visual representation of the problem. The black dot is a point on both Rect 1 and 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRq7q.png)

Note that relative to the canvas, the top left corner of Rect 1 is always considered (0,0), and Rect 2 will always appear "on top" of Rect 1.
My idea is to do a simple math equation to get the X and Y coordinates of the point on Rect 2, but so far it has not worked out.

Comment: Assuming the coordinate [0][0] corresponds to the left upper corner of the rectangle, the relative coordinates will be something like `x - Rect2[0][0].x` and `y - Rect2[0][0].y`. You should add some details of your code/data for a more precise answer.

Comment: Rect2[0][0] would be (0,0) on Rect2. It would be simple enough to do basic subtraction, but it becomes more tricky when the lengths/widths of the rectangles are not the same. In that case, would I add something like (Rect1.width/Rect2.width) into the conversion?

Comment: No, if all you want is the relative coordinates, that means the coordinates of the distance of your point to the top-left corner of the second rectangle. The sizes of either rectangles have no bearing on those -- imagine extending or contracting the rectangles by leaving their left upper corner in the same place

Comment: In that case, I suppose what I am looking for is the absolute coordinate of that point as if I were looking at Rect 2 alone.

Comment: Right, the sizes would intervene only if the coordinates are somehow normed, e.g., they should be 1 in the right lower corner

Comment: So I would just need to use the formula you provided initially?

Comment: Yes, adapted of course to your actual data structure.